# Remove broken coolant hose connection

Tags: mazda, hose

I have a super rusty [Mazda CX-9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazda_CX-9) and a connection for the coolant line snapped. I have removed the spring clip, but I am unable to remove the broken rusty part stuck in the pipe.

I have tried pulling, twisting, and inserting a straight pick, so you can free the edges. It is stuck.

How can I get this out?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple thing to do is crush it inside the hose. That should break it loose and you can then pull it out. Just try not to damage the hose while you're doing this. If you can even break part of the rusty part away from the hose, the rest should peel away from it fairly easily.

Comment: Was really tempted but everything was falling to bits, could not risk my car-luck at that time, I woukd damage the hose for sure. In the end i  actually got it off using needle nose pliers on one side and a flat screw driver at 90 degrees, kinda wiggled and pried at same time and it started to move. Found a new use for a flat-head today. Cheers for the suggestion.

Comment: @Chris - Please do one of two things: 1) place your above comment as an answer, then select it as the answer; 2) select mine as the answer. Either way, it closes out this question.